# a problem regarding conditional probability and binomial distribution.

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, binomial-distribution

Die A has 4 red and 2 white faces whereas die B has 2 red and 4 white faces . A coin (fair) is tossed once . If it falls head , the game is carried on by throwing die A alone. If it falls tail die B is used . Let $X_n =1$ or $0$ according as the nth draw is white or red . and let $S_n = X_1 + X_2 +X _3 +\cdots+X_n$

now, i tried to find the expectation and variance of $S_n$ . and i think $S_n$  it follows Bin(n,1/2).

$P(X_n= 1)=P(X_n=1\mid \text{coin turned out to be head})\cdot0.5+P(X_n=1\mid \text{coin turned out to be tail})\cdot0.5= (4/6)\cdot(0.5) +(2/6)\cdot(0.5)=0.5$

so, $S_n $follows Bin (n, 0.5)]

and in that case , E($S_n$)=.5n and

Var($S_n$)=.25n----(1)

but if i solve it in this way :

Var($S_n$)=[Var($S_n$|coin turned out to be head)]*0.5+Var[($S_n$|coin turned out to be tail)]*0.5

=$[E(S_n|$coin turned out to be head$)-E(S_n)]^2$*0.5+$[E(S_n|$coin turned out to be tail$)-E(S_n)]^2$*0.5

implies  Var($S_n$) =2n/9+$n^2$/36-----(2)

what is the reason of difference between the two results obtained in (1) and (2) ?

my book says $S_n$ doesn't follow binomial (n, 0.5) . is it the reason of this error  ? but, why isn't it binomial ?

Comment: $E[S_n\mid \text{coin turned out to be head}]$ is meaningless because behind $S_n$ there are $n$ coin tosses. You could condition on $HHTH..TH$'s and then you would have to add $2^n$ products.

Comment: no ,you got it wrong. only once the coin is tossed. if it falls head, we take the die A and keep throwing it. that means, we don't throw the coin every time before  throwing the die. read my problem carefully please.

Comment: I followed your instructions to read your problem carefully and found that you don't seem to have written it carefully. Do you really want the two dice to have the same number of faces of each colour?

Comment: No, I was asking whether you really want the two dice to have the same number of faces of each colour. You just quoted the sentence that states that the two dice have the same number of faces of each colour.

Comment: sorry . edited.  :/ thank you .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, note that a binomial distribution is for the sum of $n$ *independent identically distributed* Bernoulli variables.  This is not the case here, since $\Pr(X_2=1|X_1=1)\ne\Pr(X_2=1|X_1=0)$, and hence we're not actually dealing with a binomial distribution.  The conditional distributions of $S_n$, however, *are* binomially distributed, which we will use to our advantage.
$S_n|Heads\sim Binom(n,\frac{2}{6})$ , and $ S_n|Tails\sim Binom(n,\frac{4}{6})$.  Also, due to the symmetry of the problem, the expected value is still $E(S_n)=\frac{n}{2}$

Also, in your variance calculation, the law of total variance( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_variance ) says that it is actually:
$$Var(S_n)=Var(E(S_n|C))+E(Var(S_n|C)),$$
where $C$ represents whether the coin was heads($H$) or tails($T$). And so we need:
 $$E(Var(S_n|C)=Var(S_n|H)\cdot0.5+Var(S_n|T)\cdot0.5\\
=n(\frac{2}{6})(\frac{4}{6})\cdot0.5 + n(\frac{4}{6})(\frac{2}{6})\cdot0.5\\
=\frac{2n}{9}$$
and
$$Var(E(S_n|C))=[E(S_n|H)−E(S_n)]^2\cdot0.5+[E(S_n|T)−E(S_n)]^2\cdot0.5\\
=(\frac{2n}{6}-\frac{n}{2})^2+(\frac{4n}{6}-\frac{n}{2})^2\\
=\frac{n^2}{18}$$
And so your variance should actually be $\frac{4n+n^2}{18}$

Answer (score 0):

$S_n$ doesn't follow $Bin(n,1/2)$ but follows $Bin(n,2/3)$ with probability $1/2$ and $Bin(n,1/3)$ with probability $1/2.$ These distributions have the same variance but not the same mean.

So your second approach is the right one.

Comment: thank you for your answer. sure , you are right. but i'll like it if you help me  to remove my confusion. . 

say X is a discrete random  variable that takes values 1, 2, 3 ...n 

now the PMF of X is given by , by the basic idea of PMF , f(k)=P[x=k] , k=1,2,...n. 

here P[$X_n$= k]=  .5 . k=1,2 (ref : calculation shown in OP is it wrong ?) for all n. 

and then $X_n$ can be regarded as Bernoulli random variable. and then sum of Bernoulli is binomial.  what is wrong in it ?

Comment: Brent's answer explains the point fully.